# How can I change the icon on a custom launcher in the dock?

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, .desktop, 18.10, ubuntu-dock

I have a custom launcher.

the last line of the `.desktop` file is:

```
Icon=/home/user/bin/fritzing-0.9.3b/icons/fritzing_icon.png
```

It looks great in the folder i.e. correct icon.  It looks great on the desktop i.e. correct icon.  I followed some instructions to get it tagged to the dock using Activities and placing the launcher here:
`~/.local/share/applications/Fritzing.desktop`.

When my launcher is added to the dock, the icon disappears, and I have the generic platform on a spring icon.

How can I get the correct icon to show up in the Dock like I have it showing up on the Desktop?

Comment: Edit the .desktop file's Icon= line to reflect the actual path to the icon. /home/user/bin/... is not a valid path ( try replacing user with your username if rest of the path is correct.